# CORS request not sending cookies for https to https, but does for http

Tags: xmlhttprequest, cors

I have a CORS AJAX request I'm trying to get working from https to https. It works fine when going from http to http, but fails over SSL because it doesn't send cookies.

Is there some security restriction here? I looked at the status of `withCredentials` right before the request is made and it's set to `true`. Any idea what prevents the cookies from being sent or how to debug?

Here's the initial pre-flight (OPTIONS) request:

```
Request URL:https://mydomain.com/resource
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:X-CSRFToken
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie: [COOKIES]
Host:mydomain.com
Origin:https://www.google.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:https://www.google.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.151 Safari/535.19

Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-CSRFToken
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://www.google.com
Access-Control-Max-Age:86400
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:20
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 09 Apr 2012 00:32:51 GMT
Server:nginx/0.8.54
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

The POST request:

Request URL:https://mydomain.com/resource
    Request Method:POST
    Status Code:200 OK

```
Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:mydomain.com
Origin:https://www.google.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:https://www.google.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.151 Safari/535.19
```